# How to disable the bullets on zoomin in amcharts 4

Tags: javascript, graph, amcharts, amcharts4

I have created a chart , there are lots of customization I have added , for example X and Y lines I added these lines by doing some customization , similarly I am showing bullet as a image and the bullet is also just showing when hover .

The above is working fine , but the problem appearing is that when i zoom in or zoom out the chart then there are lots of bullets enabled , I don't want this to happen , what is the possibility.

```
Codepen Link : https://codepen.io/faizannaeem11/pen/mdoQqGg
```